# Calling a function in Perl with different properties

Tags: perl, function, module, net-snmp

I have written a Perl script that would start a SNMP session and extracting the data/counters and it's value to a csv file. There are 7 perl scripts; different properties/definition/variables on the top.. but the engine is the same.

At this point, those 7 perl scripts are redundant except for the defined variables. Is there a way to keep the execution perl script as a properties/execution file and keep the engine in a another file? This properties/execution perl script will call the engine (using the properties defined in it's own script).

So in short, I want to use the variables in their own script (as an execution as well), but calls a specific function from a unified "engine".

i.e.

retrieve_mibs1.pl retrieve_mibs2.pl
retrieve_mibs3.pl
retrieve_mibs4.pl
retrieve_mibs5.pl
retrieve_mibs6.pl
retrieve_mibs7.pl

### retrieve_mibs1.pl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Net::SNMP;

##DEFINITION START

my @Servers = (
  'server1',
  'server2',
);

my $PORT = 161;

my $COMMUNITY = 'secret';

my $BASEOID = '1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8';

my $COUNTERS = [
  [11,'TotalIncomingFromPPH'],
  [12,'TotalFailedIncomingFromPPH'],
];

##ENGINE START
sub main {
  my $stamp = gmtime();
  my @oids = ();
  foreach my $counter (@$COUNTERS) {
    push @oids,("$BASEOID.$$counter[0].0");
  }
  foreach my $server (@Servers) {
    print "$stamp$SEPARATOR$server";
    my ($session,$error) = Net::SNMP->session(-version => 1,-hostname => $server,-port => $PORT,-community => $COMMUNITY);
    if ($session) {
      my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => \@oids);
      if (defined $result) {
        foreach my $oid (@oids) {
          print $SEPARATOR,$result->{$oid};
        }
      } else {
        print STDERR "$stamp Request error: ",$session->error,"\n";
        print "$SEPARATOR-1" x scalar(@oids);
      }
    } else {
      print STDERR "$stamp Session error: $error\n";
      print "$SEPARATOR-1" x scalar(@oids);
    }
    print "\n";
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using eval: set up the variables in one file, then open the engine and eval it's content.

**variables.pl (set up your variables and call the engine):**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;
use English '-no_match_vars';

require "engine.pl"; # so that we can call it's subs

# DEFINITION START
our $VAR1    = "Hello";
our $VAR2    = "World";

# CALL THE ENGINE
print "START ENGINE:\n";
engine(); # call engine
print "DONE\n";
```

**engine.pl (the actual working stuff):**

```
sub engine{
    print "INSIDE ENGINE\n";
    print "Var1: $VAR1\n";
    print "Var2: $VAR2\n";
}
1;  # return a true value
```

Other alternatives would be:

- pass the definitions as command line parameters directly to `engine.pl` and [evaluate the contents of `@ARGV`](http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/qanda/plqa00001.shtml)
- write a [perl module](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) containing the engine and `use` this module
- store the parameters in a config file and read it in from your engine (e.g. using [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.65/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm))

Comment: Using `eval` is the wrong approach. You could have had the same effect by calling `do $file` and perl would have done the work for you. But typicaly you shouldn't use `do $file` when you could instead use `require $file`.

Comment: I tried this code, and it doesn't work for me though. The engine has more codes than just "print".

Comment: @LynxLee: yes, you do have more variables. Declare them as `our` variables instead of `my` variables and then call `engine` without any parameters and don't expand `@_` in the engine. Then you can access `$PORT`, `$COMMUNITY` and so on directly in `engine`. Editing my post to point that out.

Comment: Alright, got it. Now this code here made more sense to me. I finally separated the functions as per your code above. The engine has all subroutines with common variables. The other perl scripts are executable with it's own variables calling the engine subroutines from the Engine. Perfect, exactly what I needed for now. At least until I finally understood how to build a Perl Module. Much thanks for pointing me to this!

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts come to mind immediately:

[Build a Perl module](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=431702) for your common code, and then `require` or `use` the module as your needs dictate. (The difference is mostly whether you want to run `LynxLee::run_servers()` or `run_servers()` -- do you want the module to influence your current scope or not.)

Use symbolic links: create these symlinks: retrieve_mibs1.pl -> retrieve_mibs.pl retrieve_mibs2.pl -> retrieve_mibs.pl, and so on, then set the variables based on the program name:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use File::Basename;

my $name = basename($0);

my @Servers, $PORT, $COMMUNITY, $BASEOID, $COUNTERS;

if($name ~= /retrieve_mibs1\.pl/) {
    @Servers = (
        'server1',
        'server2',
    );

    # ...
} elsif ($name ~= /retrieve_mibs2\.pl/) {
    @Servers = (
        'server3',
        'server4',
    );

    # ...
}
```

Indexing into a hash with the name of the program to retrieve the parameters would be much cleaner, but I'm not so good at Perl references. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not so sure why we need to create symbolic links though. A Perl module would work. Still trying to build one.

Comment: @LynxLee, the symbolic links are just so you only have one program to ever maintain -- if you have multiple programs that are nearly identical, they will eventually diverge. I've seen it too many times :) so I was hoping to save you the hassle of maintaining six programs that are identical except for data declarations.

Comment: Ah.. I see what you mean now. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is so I'm guessing a little. You have code in various places that is the same each time save for some variables. This is the very definition of a subroutine.

---

Maybe the problem is that you don't know how to include the common code in those various scripts. This is fairly easy: You write that code in a perl module. This is basically a file ending in `pm` instead of `pl`. Of course you have to take care of a bunch of things such as exporting your functions. [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) should be of great help.

Comment: Yup, that's right.. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to code a perl module and have the *.pl to execute as well.